# Continuity of fibers in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism of complex irreducible varieties. As stated in for instance Mumford's red book of varieties and schemes Ch. 1 $\S$8, the generic fiber of $f$, i.e. $f^{-1}(y)$ for generic $y\in Y$, has that all its irreducible components are of the same dimension $r:=\dim X-\dim Y$.

I wonder if we can say more. For instance, is the number of irreducible components the same? And most importantly, do the irreducible components of the fibers "change continuously" as $y\in Y$ "changes continuously"? Here I am talking about contiunity in terms of complex Euclidean topology.

EDIT: I am specifically talking about generic fibers here. There are examples with non-generic fibers with different number of irreducible components.

To be more precise, we may say that a sequence of $r$-dimensional varieties $X_n$ tends to the variety $X$ if for generic $x\in X$, there is a sequence $x_n\in X_n$ tending to $x$ (in complex Euclidean topology.)

Any references are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Consider the family of curves in $\mathbb{C}^2$ given by $xy-t=0$ for various $t$. This determines a dominant map to the affine line. Then the irreducible components need not stay the same. I am unsure what “changes continuously” means to you in this example.

Comment: What exactly "changes continuously" should mean for fibers is part of the question. My suggestion for this notion is the third paragraph of the question.

Comment: Well that is why I asked because the example I gave seems to say the number of irreducible components do not stay the same with that definition as well.

Comment: Do you mean that if $t=0$, then the fiber $xy=0$ is reducible? Sure, but $t=0$ is not generic. Let me clarify that in the question.

Comment: Ah I see. Since the emphasis was on the complex Euclidean topology, I missed that adjective.

Comment: In EGA IV.9.7.9 it is proven that the set of the points of the base, such that the geometric number of irreducible components of the fiber over that point is equal to a given number, is constructible. It follows in the case of complex varieties that the number of irreducible components is constant over some Zariski open subset of $Y$.